# PHP - Resizing image while attaching it with online pdf (mpdf)

Tags: php, image, mpdf, gdlib

I am generating a pdf with some images in it. Since the images are large in size, the size of the generated PDF will also be very large. Is there a way to dynamically reduce the size of the image while attaching it to the pdf.

I tried something like this from [here](https://github.com/nomisoft/White-Hat-Classes/tree/master/Simple-Image)

```
`header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`
`include('SimpleImage.php');`
`$image = new SimpleImage();`
`$image->load($imgPath);`
`$image->resizeToWidth(150);`
`$image->output();`
```

note1 : $imgPath is passed from a loop and I'm using MPDF to generate the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the Simple_Image code that you are using, you will see the [`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) function in the `resize` method. This is called in turn by the `resizeToWidth` method - so your image IS being resampled.

Comment: Thank you foxbeefly. But here my problem is, when I generate the pdf, it shows 'failed to load pdf'. In MPDF I'm outputting the image in an image tag like this 

$html.='<div><a href="'.$path.'.$row_pic['images'].'" target="_blank"><img src = "'.$image->Output().'"/></a>';

Comment: You need to establish whether the error is with the image creation, or with the pdf creation.

Run the create pdf code without the image included - does the pdf get created now?

But looks like syntax error - you concatenation is incorrect:
`$html.='<div><a href=" ' . $path . $row_pic['images'] . ' " `

Comment: pdf is generating fine. If I call $image->output() then the pdf doesn't generate and gives me the error. Now I am using only the image tag like 
`$html.='<img src='.$image->Output().'>';`.

I am able to create the pdf without this image tag. I guess there is some error in attaching the image with the pdf

Comment: Read the notes: "The output function lets you output the image straight to the browser without having to save the file."

So I am pretty sure you need to save the image, and then include the saved image file in the pdf.

Comment: Yeah, I also had that option in my mind. But that will only consume the space in my server, right?. However, I will try that also and thank you very much for your support.

Comment: You will only be storing the downsampled image file on your server. And if that is still a problem, delete the file once the PDF is created.

Answer (score 0):

This works well and is fairly quick.

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');
$originalWidth  = imagesx($image);
$originalHeight = imagesy($image);
$scale      = min($previewWidth/$originalWidth, $previewHeight/$originalHeight);
$newWidth  = ceil($scale*$originalWidth);
$newHeight = ceil($scale*$originalHeight);
$newPic = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
imagecopyresampled($newPic, $image,0, 0, 0, 0,$newWidth, $newHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
ob_start();
imagejpeg($newPic, NULL, 70);
$jpg = ob_get_clean();
ob_clean();
$fp = fopen('newPic.jpg','w');
fwrite($fp,$jpg);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my header and this is how i used mpdf hope this will helps you

```
$htmlTable_header='<style></style><table width="100%" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:-40px;font-family:arial !important; font-size:11px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="150" valign="top"><img src="http://localhost/abc/images/abc_logo.png" width="150" height="100" border="0" alt="" title="abc" />';


$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($htmlTable_header);
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($htmlTable_footer);

$mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlTable_body);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->Output('service_report_pdf/'.$_REQUEST['id'].'.pdf',F);
```